# How does constraining a jumper actually work?

Tags: novel, jumper

In the first two novels, Davy can't teleport when he's restrained. The impression I got from that first book is that when he jumps he creates a wormhole that quickly opens up, passes over him, and then closes up. But the edge can't pass through solid matter; so no teleporting into walls or severing handcuffs.

Well, that can't be how it works exactly, since in Reflex he can somehow teleport within range of his restraints. Maybe he's actually moving along another dimension and so can drag the chains with him as long as he remains in range?

However it works though, he cannot teleport just himself and leave the cuffs or manacles behind. But, in *Exo* Cent can somehow jump into *and out of* a spacesuit it is physically *impossible* for someone to put on normally.

...unless. Maybe the key point is that she could—in principle—slide her head past the neck flange and be entirely in the suit. In that sense it's not much different than jumping into a closed room.

And it looks like I just [rubber ducked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308564/stack-exchange-has-been-taken-over-by-a-rubber-duck) my way to an answer :P

Comment: Its been to long since I read the books (10+years?), BUT, I think being restrained with a set of handcuffs would not stop him from teleporting. The cuffs would be treated just like his clothes and go with him. Its when he is Tethered to some large fixed object (like chained to a wall) that the jump will not work cause he is still "attached" to his origin point. IIRC he CAN jump, but the effect is like tearing his arms out of the cuffs since the chains cant come off the wall. Thus the pain causes him to cancel the jump. I enjoyed the books, I am going to have to re-read them again. ;)

Comment: I never knew there were more novels (and I've avoided the film).  Now I need to go hunt on Amazon and eBay for paperback copies to go with my original of the first novel.